# i cannot get why am i getting this error continously:

Tags: c++11, vector, stl

Line 1034: Char 34: runtime error: applying non-zero offset 24 to null pointer (stl_vector.h) SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:34

```
class Solution {
public:
    int numIdenticalPairs(vector<int>& nums) {
        
        int pair_count=0;
        vector<vector<int>> v;
        for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++)
        {
            v[nums[i]].push_back(i);
        }
        
        for(int i=1;i<v.size();i++)
        {
            int size=v[i].size();
            pair_count+=floor(size/2);
        }
        
        return pair_count;
    }
};
```

Comment: `v` is empty so `v[nums[i]].push_back(i);` is accessing it out of range. Perhaps you should declare it with a size specified or `resize` it.

Comment: We can help you better if you describe what you hope to accomplish. However, your code appears to have so many problems at first glance.

Comment: There is no way for us to tell which line is line 1034.